# Implicit OAuth doesn't redirect or provide call back url when using FetchAPI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, instagram-api, fetch-api

I'm using the Fetch API to trigger the [implicit login flow for the Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) in my component.

However my code returns a `force_login` URL in its response (which was a 200 status).

I only receive the access token when my I change my code from this:

```
  onLoginClick(){
    //https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
    var resource = instagramAPI+"?client_id="+this.props.clientId+"&redirect_uri="+this.props.redirect_uri+"&response_type="+this.props.type;
    fetch(resource)
    .then(function(data){
      console.log("fetched the data!")
      console.log(data.url);
      //window.location.href=data.url;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

…to this:

```
  onLoginClick(){
    //https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
    var resource = instagramAPI+"?client_id="+this.props.clientId+"&redirect_uri="+this.props.redirect_uri+"&response_type="+this.props.type;
    fetch(resource)
    .then(function(data){
      console.log("fetched the data!")
      console.log(data.url);
      window.location.href=data.url;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

***Why do I need to add the `window.location.href=data.url;` line? 
Why am I not able to run `fetch` on `data.url` and have the URL token populated in the response data?***

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected behavior is vs what the actual behavior is? What is `onLoginClick()` supposed to do?

Comment: thre's a button to click that triggers `onLoginClick()`, it should could the Instagram API and receive back a response with the access token. It seems to only work when you make a `window.location.href`. I was hoping to just have it return the proper response similar to an AJAX call that wouldn't require a reload of the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the token is not going to be in the response data it is in the returned header. If authentication is successful Instagram issues a redirect in the header. This redirect has the access token in it.

When you use window.location.href, you are telling the browser to do it's job and it will forward to the redirect and hence include the access token.

If you want the token without forwarding, then look in data.headers. I've not used JS to fetch, so I'm not sure the exact name of the header. Probably "redirect". Try:

```
console.log(data.headers);
```